# How to add regular expression extractor for more than 1 viewstate in jmeter for asp.net page

Tags: jmeter, viewstate

I have 10 different __viewstate values  in jmeter script. one is for login and others are for post methods. how can i use regular expression extractor to parameterize the viewstate for performance testing.

Comment: You can use 1 regular expression with multiple matches. Did you look up the documentation for regex extractor?

Comment: So you want to use a regular expression extractor to grab 10 values from the page?  Is this correct?  Can you provide an example?

Comment: @jgabb Yes. Posted an answer below.

Comment: I was asking the OP =) @RaGe

Comment: @jgabb ah! that makes more sense. You sounded super-aggressive when I thought you were talking to me :)

Answer (score 1):

As per [regular expression extractor documentation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor):

> If the match number is set to a negative number, then all the possible matches in the sampler data are processed. The variables are set as follows:
>
> - refName_matchNr - the number of matches found; could be 0
> - refName_n, where n = 1,2,3 etc - the strings as generated by the template
> - refName_n_gm, where m=0,1,2 - the groups for match n
> - refName - always set to the default value

Set match number `-1` for one expression to return all matches from the response.

Answer (score 0):

As RaGe mentioned in the comment, you can just use 1 **Regular Expression Extractor** to find all the matches for the given pattern.

[Regular Expression Extractor - Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/br1xQ.png)

MatchNo :

- 0 for random
- 1 for first match
- 2 for second match and so on.
- -1 for all matches

When you enter -1 & get all matches, to access the first match, use **TheVariableName_1**